# Why should I need to add init action to include PHP file to WordPress Plugin?

Tags: php, actions, init

I wanted to include a PHP file to my plugin.

So I added following code to top of my plugin.

```
require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/test-file.php');
```

But it didn't worked.

Then I tried following method.

```
add_action("init", function () {

    require_once( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'inc/test-file.php');

});
```

It worked.

So I want to know that what is the problem is my first code? Why it didn't worked and why second one worked?

Comment: And what was the problem with the first attempt?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż It is not including. I checked it  adding a var_dump / echo to test-file.php

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Try using `file_exists( 'path-here' );` to see if the file actually exists.